# How do I trigger a zap through a shopify page view?

Tags: javascript, shopify, zapier

I need to build a product page view counter to display on the product page. I plan to use zapier to trigger the JS code since I'm using data from google analytics to push page count to the product metafield. I'm having trouble figuring out how to trigger this zap through a product page view.

Comment: you don't really need that much of a setup, you can use the amazing [StatsHat](https://www.stathat.com/) service for that, as they have a **counter** api, that all you need is to send the productId and it counts automatically... they just retrieve the info from their API

Comment: How do I do this without using stathats?

Comment: StatsHat is a free service, so it has the advantage of storing data without you paying for it, and you can do it in javascript on the client browser or embed code in the item page... without StatsHat, I would probably sign up for [FaunaDB](https://fauna.com/) and use them to store the data and use the secure REST/Graph API to add product and retrieve a count to show on the front page... you need to store the data in a global place (database, files, etc) and make it easy to sum and retrieve the information